# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in GSMCommunication.dll

Tags: vb.net

I have created windows based application to send sms using vb.net through GSM Modem. In Windows-XP 32 bit system sms are sending properly, but in windows-7 64 bit system throwing error like "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in GSMCommunication.dll".i have posted my code below,

```
           Imports GsmComm.GsmCommunication
           Imports System.Management
           Imports GsmComm
           Imports SMS

           Private Sub btnsend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsend.Click


            Dim mos As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem")
            Dim port As Integer = 0
            Dim PortAfterRemoval As String = ""
            For Each mo As ManagementObject In mos.Get()
                Dim portno As String = mo("AttachedTo").ToString()
                PortAfterRemoval = portno.Substring(3)
            Next
            Dim m_RegKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine
            m_RegKey = m_RegKey.OpenSubKey("HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM")
            Dim szComPorts() As String = m_RegKey.GetValueNames
            Dim p As Integer = 0
            Do While (p <= szComPorts.GetUpperBound(0))

                Dim portno As String = m_RegKey.GetValue(szComPorts(p)).ToString()
                PortAfterRemoval = portno.Substring(3)
                p = (p + 1)
                port = Convert.ToInt16(PortAfterRemoval)
                'Setting Data Transmition rate for modem
                Dim baudRate As Integer = 9600
                Dim timeout As Integer = 300
                Dim dlg As New frmConnection()
                dlg.SetData(port, baudRate, timeout)
                Try
                    CommSetting.Comm_Port = port
                    CommSetting.Comm_BaudRate = baudRate
                    CommSetting.Comm_TimeOut = timeout
                    CommSetting.comm = New GsmCommMain(port, baudRate, timeout)
                    CommSetting.comm.Open()

                    If CommSetting.comm.IsConnected() Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        CommSetting.comm.Close()
                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try

            Loop
            Dim SmsObj As New Send()
            SmsObj.SendSms(strsmsText, PhoneNo)
            CommSetting.comm.Close()
            m_RegKey.Close()
           End Sub
```

kindly help me to rectify this issue, thank u in advance

Comment: If the DLL is a non-.NET DLL, then you may need to mark your program as 32-bit (set "Target CPU" to "x86" in "Advanced Compiler Settings" if you're using Visual Studio).

Comment: Hi Thank u for your reply, its .Net dll only, and another problem is GSM modem port is opening but its not connecting for this code, for other code its working fine